# SharePoint 2013 workflow does not send email

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I have created an approval SharePoint 2013 workflow. However, it executes all the actions before 'Send email' action but executing 'Send email' gives below exception:

> RequestorId: f679ccb9-2fc0-8099-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500
>   {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["1058"],"SPRequestGuid":["f679ccb9-2fc0-8099-9fd6-bcce66215203"],"request-id":["f679ccb9-2fc0-8099-9fd6-bcce66215203"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon,
>   29 Oct 2018 05:09:27
>   GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]}
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.Execute

I have even created a new workflow just to send email (hardocoded user), it logs successfully before the 'Send email' action but gives the above exception.

The SMTP is configured properly and SharePoint 2010 workflows sends email on same web applications.

I have just re-installed workflow manager and applied the CU5 updates.

The internal status is "Suspended".

**Update**:

I just tried to add the user into a group and checked the "Send email invitation", it doesn't send email either.

**Workflow screenshots:**

[image]

Even after removing the Email action out of the App step, issue persist.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is the error it is showing before going into suspended state? (check it immediately after workflow starts).

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have pasted the error exception above.

Comment: Yes, but that is the error after workflow goes to suspended state. but workflow shows the action it is taking before going to suspended state. check the information it is showing just after workflow starts and before going into suspended state. that will be helpful.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have checked just after the "Started" state, but 'i' icon does not appear to check the information. 
The information icon is visible only after "Suspended" state.

Comment: strange. it should be saying like "attempting or retrying.....some action".

Comment: In Email action, in "to" field --> select the user who created item --> his login name/email address property --> try this once.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have coded the user, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know , the error is with 500 status and i can see sharepoint health score as well . 
Sometimes it happens because of memory related problems.

I would suggest you to test the same workflow in some other environment and with same domain account .

Let me know if you get error in other envt as well , then we can try couple of things.

Answer (score 0):

If the email doesn't get send when you add user that means the emailing is not configured correctly. Review settings of your outgoing email.

1. Ping the email server does it respond (if it doesn't then review firewall rules)
2. Check with team that handles your email server do they get any errors.
3. Review the Event viewer logs for any events when you try to send the email.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 workflows sends email for same web application.

Comment: This is strange I would focus on resolving first problem with email when you add users. In My case that resolved problems with sending emails from WF2013

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error for SharePoint Designer Workflows. The most common mistake for getting this error is **"LOGGING"**. Logging in the workflow history is limited to 255 characters.

Re-check the logging in you workflow and if the logging content exceeds or you think will exceed 255 characters then please remove it or replace with shorter text and the try running again.

Comment: "Before email" and "After email" are the two logs in the whole workflow.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the workflow or request header?

Comment: I have added the screenshots.

Comment: It should work. Check if both users are resolved. Try sending blank emails. Have you tried the same workflow on another site?